# Share code between classes in Objective-C without inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties, multiple-inheritance

Since Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance, is there some other mechanism to share code between classes?

I'm writing a Cocoa library on top of an existing xml schema.  Many elements in the schema (for example, ) are used in multiple types.  I was hoping to centralize this somehow, so that I didn't have to add `@property NSString *name` and the associated code to generate the xml for the name property in every single class that has a name attribute.  That would be fairly straightforward if multiple inheritance were supported, but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

The best thing I can think of is to create a common superclass that has a superset of methods to encode each optional property, then call the appropriate methods (i.e. `encodeName`) in the encoding method for each class.  Does that seem like the best way to go?

Comment: I used the same technique in my first Objective-C project.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you create a new [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) with your properties/functions etc and add said category to NSObject. That would make all properties and functions available to all subclasses of NSObject. It's not exactly multiple inheritance but provides a great amount of flexibility.

Comment: Is that better than putting all my methods on a shared base class?  In particular, I didn't think that you could add properties to a category.

Comment: You gain the benefit of being able to subclass from objects that you actually WANT too, as opposed to an artificial super class that is just a holder for your common functions. If you need to add properties to a class then use an extension and create the getter/setter yourself, following KVC.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to add data to a class at run time using the [runtime's Associative Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) functions. It's a little deeper than normal SDK work, but works quite well. It's not the same as a full property with getters and setters, but it does associate objects with an instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods are only required on certain objects then maybe a sub class from that class is the way to go or a category on that specific class would be better. The category on NSObject is quite a wide net to cast.

If you want to add additional state then sub classing is probably your safest bet.

If you do add a category make sure you prefix your methods with something unique so to avoid any conflicts. E.g. `PSMySpecialMethod` as opposed to `mySpecialMethod`